# Function tools library in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

What is a good TS style way to implement a library of tool functions such as unit conversions?
I have them all in a JS file, but would like to make it as TS compliant as possible. It seems having a provider for this is bit overkill. Or I could go for a class of `new Tools().feetToInch()` , or `static` member functions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a class to be *TS Compliant*. Just add a `.d.ts` file with the definitions of everything you wrote in JavaScript so anyone using TypeScript will get the advantage of type definitions.